# How to bind value from Viewmodel to usercontrol in view

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls

I have a window, that contains a usercontrol.
The usercontrol have a dependency value, which I need to bind to a value on the windows viewmodel.

But, no matter what I try, I end up with `null`.

So, time to put some code up.

This is where I add my usercontrol, and I assume this is where I have my problem.
I'm trying to bind the "PlantToSearch" property, on the usercontrol, to the "SelectedPlant" in the viewmodel.

```
    <my:BomSearchControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             PlantToSearch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SaveAsWindow}},
                                Path=DataContext.SelectedPlant}"
                         Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    </my:BomSearchControl>
```

I have tried to point it to the SaveAsWindow's datacontext, but this doesn't seem to work.

On my BomSearchControl, I have the following code, for the dependency property:

```
public static DependencyProperty PlantToSearchProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PlantToSearch", typeof(Plant), typeof(BomSearchControl));

    public Plant PlantToSearch
    {
        get { return (Plant)GetValue(PlantToSearchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PlantToSearchProperty, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any `BindingExpression` errors in your debug output window?

Comment: I agree with DHN.  Check your output window for binding errors.

Comment: No binding errors in output window.

Comment: Oh shit, I'm an idiot. I forgot OnPropertyChanged in my viewmodel, when I set the SelectedPlant. Hah. Wasted all yesterday on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was really embarrasing.
I simply forgot to update my property, in the UI, after setting it in the viewmodel.

So basically, the fix was to add `OnPropertyChanged` in my setter.

```
    private Plant _selectedPlant;
    public Plant SelectedPlant
    {
        get { return _selectedPlant; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedPlant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPlant");
        }
    }
```